# I2S 通信を用いた録音を実行しようとするとエラー: 'AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_I2S' was not declared in this scope

Tags: spresense

SonyのSpresenseにてI2S通信を用いて録音を行おうとしています。
コンパイル環境はArduino IDEで、Windows10です。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html
の "1.9. MP3 形式で録音する" を参考にしています。

サイトに記載のある通り、Spresenseのスケッチ例 "Audio/application/recorder" を読みだして、コンパイルが問題なく通ることは確認できました。

I2S通信を行うために、サイトの指示通り以下のようにコードを変更しましたが、変更後にエラーとなってしまいます。

#### 変更前

```
theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC);
```

#### 変更後

```
theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_I2S);
```

#### エラーメッセージ

```
'AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_I2S' was not declared in this scope
```

AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_I2Sが定義されていないことによるエラーかと思うのですが、どのようにしたら解決できますでしょうか。

どなたか御教授ください。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

Spresense は I2Sポート からの音声記録には対応しておりません。
チュートリアルの記載の誤りです。大変申し訳ありません。

デジタル音声を記録されたい場合は、デジタルマイクをお使いください。
デジタルマイクの接続方法は、次のURLに記載されています。

[デジタルマイクの接続方法](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%81%AE%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

この度はドキュメントの不備によってご不便をお掛け致しました。
ご指摘いただいた内容は早急に反映いたします。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: 迅速なご回答をいただき、ありがとうございます。了解致しました、I2Sでの入力ではなく、マイク接続による入力で録音動作を行うように致します。